# Is it possible to have circular dependencies in pipes in C?

Tags: python, c, linux

## Question

I'm trying to write a C program that takes two programs and redirects the stdin/out of each like this:

### Program A

stdin: the stdout of program B

### Program B

stdin: the stdout of program A

I've tried using two pipes (and closing the unused ends) but I'm getting `Broken Pipe [Errno 32]`.  Is it possible to have a "circular dependency" like this with pipes in C?

---

## My Implementation

To test my C program, I have written two simple programs (A and B). I've tested A and B thoroughly.

### Program A

Program A does 4 things:

1. Read the contents of a file
2. Write the contents to stdout
3. Read from stdin until EOF
4. Write that ^ to an output file

### Program B

Program B does three things:

1. Reads from stdin until EOF
2. Reverses those bytes ^
3. Writes those bytes to stdout ^

### My C Program

My C program takes as input two programs and attempts to hook them together as described above. Unfortunately, I'm getting `Broken Pipe [Errno 32]`.

## Code

Program A:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import sys

def main():
    # read from some source other than stdin
    with open("test_in", "r") as in_file:
        inbuf = in_file.read()

    # write the buffer to stdout
    print(inbuf)
    # read from stdin
    outbuf = sys.stdin.read()

    # write the buffer to the secondary source
    with open("test_out", "w+") as w_file:
        w_file.write(outbuf)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Program B:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import sys

def transform(buf):
    return "".join(list(reversed(buf)))

def main():
    inbuf = sys.stdin.read()
    print(transform(inbuf))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

My C Program (the part that matters):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  pids[i] = fork();
  if (pids[i] == -1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to fork off process %d.\n", i);
    exit(1);
  }
  if (pids[i] == 0) {
    // child
    if (i == 0) {
        dup2(fds[0], 0);
        dup2(fds[3], 1);
        close(fds[1]);
        close(fds[2]);
        execvp(program_a, (char*[]){program_a, (char*)(NULL)});
        fprintf(stderr, "execvp %s failed.\n", program_a);
        exit(1);
    } else if (i == 1) {
        dup2(fds[2], 0);
        dup2(fds[1], 1);
        close(fds[0]);
        close(fds[3]);
        execvp(program_b, (char*[]){program_b, (char*)(NULL)});
        fprintf(stderr, "execvp %s failed.\n", program_b);
        exit(1);
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: Line %d This should never happen.\n", __LINE__);
        exit(1);
    }
  } else {
    // parent
  }
}

close(fds[0]);
close(fds[1]);
close(fds[2]);
close(fds[3]);

int statuses[2];
waitpid(pids[0], &statuses[0], 0);
waitpid(pids[1], &statuses[1], 0);
```

fds[0] and fds[1] are the read and write ends of the first pipe, respectively. fds[2] and fds[3] are that of the second.

Comment: `// parent`. That's one of the main problems. The pipes are still open in the parent process.

Comment: Prog A, step 3, halts on reading from stdin.  Prog B, step 1, halts on reading from stdin.  Does Prog C write to A or B's stdin?  It does not appear to.  You refer to pipes but you don't use the `popen` call nor named pipes.

Comment: @kaylum Thanks, my program no longer hangs. I'm getting Broken Pipe now though.

Comment: Ask a new question. And this time please provide a [mcve]. It was easy to guess that the parent already had the pipe open for this question. But we can't keep guessing. We need to see *complete* code. If I had to guess I would say you may be closing the pipes before finishing all the `fork` calls. But that's just a guess as can't see your actual code.

Comment: Yes, my guess is correct. You should only close the pipes after the `for` loop has completed invoking all the `fork` calls or at least only close the ones that no longer need to be duped in a later iteration.

Comment: Well -- since there aren't any answers (just helpful comments), amending this question into a new one is arguably still acceptable at this point; it's after a question is answered that changing it into something new/different (to which prior answers don't apply) is frowned on.